# Google recaptcha audio text input display bug

Tags: javascript, html, css, recaptcha

The new google recaptcha on default sizing does not get wider for the audio selection. In the html, this text is included in the text window:

```
Type the numbers you hear to solve the challenge. Press SPACE to begin the audio. Press the R key to replay the audio."
```

However, when displayed it cuts off the rest of the instructions so it looks like this and the directions are unclear:

[image: Google Recaptcha layout problem]

It seems to be a google recaptcha bug. Until they fix it, has anyone come up with a workaround? Just editing the css doesn't work since all the css is manipulated by an external script and the popup doesn't appear until the user is interacting with the captcha.